# Sync timers between two devices using Multipeer Connectivity?

Tags: ios, swift, multipeer-connectivity

I've come across a few posts that kind of address my issue, but none of them actually have the answer that I'm looking for. I'm using Multipeer Connectivity to connect between two devices, and I want to execute a block of code at the exact same time, with as little latency as possible. I've gone through sending timestamps from the host to another peer to start a timer at the same time (with the Date class), but there is always at least 0.3 to 0.5 seconds of latency. The problem is that the device times aren't synced perfectly. Is there any third-party framework or solution that would allow me to run code at the same time on both devices? One example of this is the app AmpMe, which syncs music across many devices. I'm using Swift 3, by the way.

Comment: Hello @themaanas ,
is there any way you have found for play music at same time in near by device like AmpMe App?
I have checked MultipeerConnectivity Framework that provided by Apple.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a time server to either synchronize their clocks or calculate the offset between their clocks, and then use those offsets to start your timers at the exact same instant on both devices.

Comment: How would I go about calculating the offset? This is keeping in mind that I need to do so across multiple devices, not just two.

Comment: Find a time server. Fetch the time from that time server. Compare to current system time. Calculate the difference for the current device. Assuming good latency, this should be accurate enough for all but the most critical synchronization.

Comment: That still wouldn't let me synchronize times between the devices. It would only allow me to know how much one device time differed from the real time, rather than how much one device time differed from another device.

Comment: Once you know how much each device's clock differs from real time you can trigger events based on actual time (using the offsets to adjust.) Thus you CAN synchronize the devices.

Comment: I'm still not getting the logic behind that. I can retrieve the actual time with an NTP framework, but what do I do with the device time so that it waits for the other device to sync with it?

Comment: One method that I had was to find the difference in times with one device and the NTP time, then send that to the other device. This device would then compare it's difference in times with the first device, decide which one was more, so that the one which was closest to the actual NTP time would wait for the other to catch up.

Comment: For each device, use a time server to calculate it's offset to real time. Then, broadcast a "do <action> at future time ABC" message, using real time units. On each device, adjust the real time to device time using the previously calculated offset, and start a timer that will trigger the desired event at the desired time.